# Validate form before submitting to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello I'm implementing a login page everything is working fine from the PHP side but now I would implement one more function using jQuery: I would like to check if the fields of the login are empty and if not than print something on the page, otherwise continue with php, how to do that?

Here is part of my HTML code:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="login-exec.php" name="loginForm" method="post" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" data-ajax="false">
    <fieldset>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label class="ui-input-text" for="login">Login:</label>
            <input name="login" type="text" class="textfield" id="login" />
        </div>                                  
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">                                      
            <label class="ui-input-text" for="password">Password:</label>
            <input name="password" type="password" class="textfield" id="password"/> 
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: `if(empty($_POST['login'])){ die("Fill in this field."); } else{ // continue }` do the same for the `password` field. You could even use one condition for both along with an `OR` operator => `||` which is one way to do it. We need to see your actual (PHP) handler to make 100% sure we can give you a definite answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry Ive added it now im handling the php file through action="login-exec.php" is there a way to firstly check the fields from client-side and then send the values to server-side so trigger my php file?

Comment: I can't write code from the top of my head regarding `client-side`, I'm mostly PHP (server-side) myself. However, the answer given below, seems to be "somewhat" of a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind an event to the submission of the form (Note: NOT the click of a submit button). That's where your code goes that checks the form, and if necessary, stops it from being posted.

```
$('#loginForm').on('submit', function(e){
    if ($('#login').val()=='' || $('#password').val()==''){
        e.preventDefault();
        // alert('Fill in both fields');
        // You can use an alert or a dialog, but I'd go for a message on the page
        $('#errormsg').text('Fill in both fields').show();
    }else{
        // do nothing and let the form post
    }
});
```

If you prefer to show a message than use a dialog, somewhere on the page, preferably near the Submit button add the errormsg div

```
<p id="errormsg" style="display:none;"></p>
```

Comment: Do I need to put a trigger on the button? Coz doing like this isnt working :)

Comment: No you should never put a trigger to submit a form on a button. Have you properly added the jQuery inside of `$(function(){});`? And have you got jQuery loaded first? Do you see an error in your console (in Chrome press F12 then click Console)?