# validate form before submit php

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, validation, contact-form-7

I have a question to ask.

I have a form that the user has to fill up. There are a couple of fields that have restrictions (for example the name can't be empty). The problem is that everytime I press the submit button I get a popup saying that the name can't be empty but it's automatically redirect to an other page. So the question is: How can I modify my code to do the validation before being redirect to the page or chen the user clicks outside or press tab?

In order to achive this Im using PHP, Contact Form 7 and wordpress.
Here is my code:

**php function createAccount.php**

```
<?php 
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
include ('../../../wp-config.php');
global $wpdb;    
$nameErr = "";
if(isset($_POST['next']))
{
$name=addslashes($_POST['cName']);
$surname=addslashes($_POST['cSurname']);
$email=addslashes($_POST['cEmail']);
$phone =addslashes($_POST['cPhone']);
$otherPhone=implode($_POST['cOtherPhone']);
$languages=implode(' | ', $_POST['cLanguages']);
$address=addslashes($_POST['cAddress']);
$neighborhood=$_POST['cNeighborhood'];
$pswd=addslashes($_POST['cPswd']);
$service=$_POST['cService'];
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if(empty($_POST["cName"])) {
        $message = "wrong answer";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');
    </script>";
}
}else{

$wpdb->insert("Client",array(
"cName"=>$name,
"cSurname"=>$surname,
"cEmail"=>$email,
"cPhone"=>$phone,
"cOtherPhone"=>$otherPhone,
"cLanguages"=>$languages,
"cAddress"=>$address,
"cNeighborhood"=>$neighborhood,
"cPswd"=>$pswd,
"cService"=>$service
));
print_r("uq");
}  
}
 $wpdb->show_errors();
?>
```

**Contact form 7 page**

```
<form action="/wp-content/plugins/my-codes/signUp.php" method="post">
[contact-form-7 id="422" title="Member Signup"]
</form>
```

**Contact Form**

```
<p>Your Name (required)<br /> </p>
[text* cName id:cName]

<p>Your Surname (required)<br /> </p>
[text* cSurname id:cSurname]

<p>Your Email (required)<br /></p>
[email* cEmail id:cEmail] 

<label> Your Telephone Number (required)
[tel* cPhone id:cPhone tel-106 placeholder "123 456 789"] </label>

<label> Other Telephone Number (required)
[tel* cOtherPhone id:cOtherPhone tel-106 placeholder "123 456 789"] </label>

<h3>What languages do your prefer?</h3>
<input id=cLanguages type="checkbox" name=cLanguages[] value="English">
<use_label_element for="check_14">English</use_label_element>

<input id=cLanguages type="checkbox" name=cLanguages[] value="Hebrew">
<use_label_element for="check_15">Hebrew</use_label_element>

<input id=cLanguages type="checkbox" name=cLanguages[] value="French">
<use_label_element for="check_16">French</use_label_element>

<input id=cLanguages type="checkbox" name=cLanguages[] value="Spanish">
<use_label_element for="check_17">Spanish</use_label_element>

<p>Your Address (required)<br /> </p>
[text* cAddress id:cAddress]

<select cNeighborhood id:cNeighborhood name=cNeighborhood>
<option value="Bat Yam">Bat Yam</option>
<option value="Raanana">Raanana</option>
</select>

<label> Create Password (required)
[text* cPswd id:cPswd] </label>

<label> Confirm Password (required)
[text* cPswd id:cPswd] </label>

<label> Pick a Service (required)</label>
<select cService id:cService name=cService>
<option value="Babysitter">Babysitter</option>
<option value="Cleaner">Cleaner</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="next">
```

Any help please? thanks!

**UPDATE CONTACT FORM**

```
<form id="commentForm" action="/wp-content/plugins/my-            codes/createAccount.php" method="post">
<p>Your Name (required)<br /> </p>
[text* cName id:cName]

<p>Your Surname (required)<br /> </p>
[text* cSurname id:cSurname]

<p>Your Email (required)<br /></p>
[email* cEmail id:cEmail] 

<label> Your Telephone Number (required)
[tel* cPhone id:cPhone tel-106 placeholder "123 456 789"] </label>
<label> Other Telephone Number (required)
[tel* cOtherPhone id:cOtherPhone tel-106 placeholder "123 456 789"] </label>

<h3>What languages do your prefer?</h3>
<input id=cLanguages type="checkbox" name=cLanguages[] value="English">
<use_label_element for="check_14">English</use_label_element>

<input id=cLanguages type="checkbox" name=cLanguages[] value="Hebrew">
<use_label_element for="check_15">Hebrew</use_label_element>

<input id=cLanguages type="checkbox" name=cLanguages[] value="French">
<use_label_element for="check_16">French</use_label_element>

<input id=cLanguages type="checkbox" name=cLanguages[] value="Spanish">
<use_label_element for="check_17">Spanish</use_label_element>

<p>Your Address (required)<br /> </p>
[text* cAddress id:cAddress]

<select cNeighborhood id:cNeighborhood name=cNeighborhood>
<option value="Bat Yam">Bat Yam</option>
<option value="Raanana">Raanana</option>
</select>

<label> Create Password (required)
[text* cPswd id:cPswd] </label>

<label> Confirm Password (required)
[text* cPswd id:cPswd] </label>

<label> Pick a Service (required)</label>
<select cService id:cService name=cService>
<option value="Babysitter">Babysitter</option>
<option value="Cleaner">Cleaner</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js">   </script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#commentForm").validate();
</script>
```

I want to be redirected to

> /wp-content/plugins/my-codes/createAccount.php

when I press submit button.

Comment: You want to use client side validation?

Comment: I think is the best option no?

Comment: There are two types of validation:
1. Client Side
2. Server side.
which one do you want?

Comment: Client Side, I dont need to go to the server for anything. I only need to check that the fields are not empty and stuff like that

Comment: You should still validate all data on the server side too as JS can be easily bypassed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate form before submitting to php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599917/validate-form-before-submitting-to-php)

Answer (score 1):

In the `<input id=cLanguages type="checkbox" name=cLanguages[] value="English">` for example, you can add the required attribute like so :

```
<input id=cLanguages type="checkbox" name=cLanguages[] value="English" required>
```

There is an automatic validation for the required fields in HTML, it is available for all types of input.

Comment: And then should I have an automatic message? saying its a required file?

Comment: Exactly, you can also create your own validation with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use jquery client side validation:

[Jquery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

```
$('#form_id').validate({
    rules:
    {
        elem_name:
        {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages:
    {
        elem_name:
        {
            required: "Mandatory field"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I understand. But then when I press the button to submit, nothing is happening.

Comment: Im checking now. Uodate my answer in the midwhile

Comment: It say: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: Include the required js in the page

Comment: updated. But still nothing is happening when I press the button. What am I missing here?

Comment: "jQuery in WordPress is in compatibility mode by default. That means that the typical $ shortcut for jQuery doesn't work" ( [see here](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/) ). You have to wrap your jquery code with `(function($) { ... })( jQuery );` in order to make it working

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery Validation Plugin for validation and form submission

you can specify custom messages as well

```
// Setup form validation on the #register-form element
$("#register-form").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        firstname: "required",
        lastname: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        agree: "required"
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        firstname: "Please enter your first name",
        lastname: "Please enter your last name",
        password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
        },
        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        agree: "Please accept our policy"
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Should I add this code into the contact form? After all the fields or the correct way is doing it separtely?

Comment: Its not working. When I press the button, nothing happen.. any ideas? No errors in the console either